# How to get rid of content flash using $firebaseObject

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Currently I'm loading my firebase data right in my controller like this:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $firebaseObject) {
    $scope.users = {};
    var myDB = new Firebase('https://mydb.firebaseio.com/');
    $firebaseObject(myDB.child("users")).$bindTo($scope, "user");
});
```

This way after the page is loaded, there is a delay during which the data is retrieved from firebase, therefore at first the page appears to be empty until the data arrives. This is unconvinient.

In order to prevent this flashy behavior I wanted to resolve the required data in my $routeProvider but wasn't able to get a promise.

**How to *properly* get rid of the content flashing?**
Is there a way to get a promise so one can resolve the $firebaseObject before the view is shown?

*Please* do not offer quick-and-dirty-solutions containing ng-cloak, ng-hide, ng-show etc.

Comment: What's wrong with a solution using ng-cloak etc? They are, in fact, designed for dealing with rendering issues and can be [fairly elegant](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/components/ngcloak/ngcloak-decorator.js); decoupled from views and controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$loaded()` promise in your `resolve` function.

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/home", {
  // the rest is the same for ui-router and ngRoute...
  controller: "HomeCtrl",
  templateUrl: "views/home.html",
  resolve: {
    "myObject": ["$firebaseObject", function($firebaseObject) {
      var ref = new Firebase("...");
      return $firebaseObject(ref).$loaded();
    }]
  }
})
```

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-objects.html

Check out the AngularFire docs on routing in authentication for better guidance on handling routes with promises in general.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html